# Can the same entity be declared in two different namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, language-lawyer

I have a question about §7.3.4/6 in the c++ standard:

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different
>   namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do
>   not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

Is seems to suggest that there are cases where the same entity is declared in two different namespaces. Else the wording "and the declarations do not declare the same entity" would not have been needed.

Any examples of such situations? Remember that using-declarations are not declaring any entity. They are just referring to a declaration of an entity done elsewhere (possibly indirectly via other using-declarations). Using-declarations are introducing their name into a declarative region however, but that is another thing.

Remember also that using-directives are not declaring any entities either.

An finally observe that out of line definitions (definitions using qualified names) for namespace members are not declaring anything in the namespace where they occur, but only in the target namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really doesn't apply to the using declaration. It says: "finds a declaration [...] in two different namespaces", not "entity that was declared in two different namespaces".

Comment: _"Remember that using-declarations are not declaring any entity."_ Then why are they called using-declarations?

Comment: There are other declarations that are not declaring any entities, for example: static_assert declarations. The term declaration is used in two ways in the standard.

Comment: For a member name it declares it? What do you mean?

Comment: @Supremum: Well for `static_assert` that's a bit of a hack so you can put them in a class definintion. Not sure it counts. Can you think of any other examples?

Comment: using-directives There are a lot of wierd definitions. They are listed in the declartions section of the c++ standard.

Comment: Anyways it seems like using-declarations are at least declaring names, whatever that means. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But using declarations do declare names for entities.  From the C++11 standard, §7.3.3[namespace.udecl]/1:

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.
>
> > *using-declaration*:
> >
> > > `using typename`<sub>*opt*</sub> *nested-name-specifier unqualified-id* `;`
> > >         `using ::` *unqualified-id* `;`
>
> **The member name specified in a using-declaration is declared in the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.**

Comment: @Supremum This doesn't really apply to the question. A *using-declaration* declares a new name, but this wouldn't make it possible to really find the same name in two different entities. If you try to introduce the same name twice with a *using-declaration*, that's a hard error. Only a *using-directive* would make that possible, which is the section in which the sentence you quoted from appears.

Comment: Damn, the c++ standard really messed things up when it comes to declarations. In §7.3.4/6 what is meant by the namespace where name lookup finds the declaration for a name? In namespace N { static int i = 1; } using namespace N; using N::i; int main() { i = 2; } In what namespace is  i  found during the unqualified name lookup?

Comment: @Supremum In `::`, because of the *using-declaration*. Without that, in `N` because of the *using-directive*. Without both, nowhere.

Comment: So namespace N { static int i = 1; } namespace M { struct i {}; } using N::i; using M::i int main() { sizeof(i); }

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that introducing a name into a declarative region is the same a declaring that name there, but that declaring an entity is not the same are declaring a name in a declarative region.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with `extern`. From [dcl.link]:

> Two declarations for a function
>   with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that
>   appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function. **Two declarations for a variable with C
>   language linkage with the same name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different
>   namespace scopes refer to the same variable.**

For example:

```
namespace A {
    extern "C" int x;
}

namespace B {
    extern "C" int x;
}

extern "C" {
    int x;
}

namespace D {
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
}
```

`A::x` and `B::x` (and `::x`) are all the same entity. As a result, `D::x` is not ill-formed.

---

Upon further reflection, with a combo of *using-declaration*s and *using-directive*s, we can come up with an easier example that doesn't rely on `extern`:

```
namespace A {
    int i;   
}

namespace B {
    using A::i;
}

namespace C {
    using A::i;
}

namespace D {
    using namespace B;
    using namespace C;
}

int main() {
    D::i = 4; // name lookup finds `i` declared in two different namespaces,
              // B and C. However, both of those declarations refer to the
              // same entity, A::i
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's a sentence about variables in there. I can write a different example.

Comment: @Supremum I added a simpler, non-`extern` example - this one probably would be easier to see.

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace A{
void fun(){}
}
namespace B{
void fun(){}
}
int main()
{
using namespace A;
using namespace B;
fun()//ambiguous call here because this entity is present in both the namespaces 

}
```

In above code call to fun is ambiguous as look up will not able to find the correct fun to call .
Second example is below :

```
namespace N { namespace A {int i;} }

struct A {static int i;};

using namespace N;

int i = A::i;
```

In later case ,call is ambiguous as entity 'A' is present in both the namespaces (N and global namespace) .
Hope this will help

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The OP knows both of these things. When the code is ill-formed because different entities are named, and when the entities are a function. The OP is asking about the third, implied case, in which the two declarations do name the same non-function entity, and how this can be possible.